# Python array labels for ease of access

Tags: python

In lua you can do

```
local player_inf = {
    ["velo"] = {
        x = nil,
        y = nil,
    }
}
```

is there something similar in python?

Comment: `dictionaries`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries Check out this for more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```py
palyer_info = {"velocity": 
                {'x': None,
                 'y': None,
                 'true_velocity': None
                }
              }
```